# cannot add new sqlite database connection using idea13

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea

I cannot add new sqlite database connection using idea13 using database viewer and I am getting this error

```
 IllegalArgumentException: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of org/jetbrains/android/database/AndroidDbUtil.replaceByDirAllowedName must not be null: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of org/jetbrains/android/database/AndroidDbUtil.replaceByDirAllowedName must not be null
```

Comment: I am sure that the problem related to the sdk because when I am removing it I can add database connection again !